# Getting NullPointerException in TransferService.java , AWS S3 Android SDK for random user

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 Cloud storage to my application which is working fine but still the Crash logging tool showing the crashes for `TransferService.java`

here are my implementation details :

1) Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.6'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.6'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.6'
```

2) Create S3 client:

```
public static AmazonS3Client getAWS3Client() {
    if (s3Client == null) {
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                AppDeligate.getInstance(),
                Credentials.IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // Identity Pool ID
               Credentials.REGION // Region
        );

        return s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    }
    return s3Client;
}
```

3) Create object of TransferUtility:

```
 TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(AppDeligate.getAWS3Client(), mContext);
```

4) Complete Crashlog:

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService@21f28350 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2886)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
 Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService.onStartCommand(TransferService.java:172)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2869)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Just wondering: even it would work, shouldnt that method be rather synchronized?

Comment: Try updating your sdk to 2.3.7, This seems related to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/223

Answer (score 0):

A debug hint to get you going:

1. See if you can get access to the TransferService source code (starting point could be [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android)
2. Check what this code is doing on line 172; and if you can relate that to *anything* your code is doing upfront

One can easily find the way to [TransferService](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/a74118ccac8476888fc109697ace31113b340e26/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transferutility/TransferService.java) ... but it looks like this is a *newer* version; as line 172 is empty.

But I think my idea could give you something to get going.